# Data truncation:Truncated incorrect Double value

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

Trying to update an record that I search for in a database, I then try to change an value and click the update button but I keep getting this error of

> "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'sdjajsdaj@gmail.com'"

```
   private void upbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Connection conn=null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students", "root","Splash7727#" );
        String sql= "update  studentinfo set Fname = ?,Lname = ?,gender = ?,age = ?, CNumber = ?,email = ? where studentId = ?";
        PreparedStatement  pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(sidTxt.getText()));
        pst.setString(2,FnameTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(3, LnameTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(4, genTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(5, ageTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(6, cnmTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(7,emlTxt.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Updated");
        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think message is clear. Why are you specifying an email address for a column that is expecting a double value? Also, why would you use setString(…) when trying to set a double value. Look at your SQL statement where you specify the parameters and look at your PreparedStatement where you set each value. You have a problem matching values with your parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numberinhg is off

You defined your email text as id

```
    pst.setInt(7,Integer.parseInt(sidTxt.getText()));
    pst.setString(1,FnameTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(2, LnameTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(3, genTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(4, ageTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(5, cnmTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(6,emlTxt.getText());
    pst.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't matching the ordering of how you're setting data for the statement.

Your query should look like this:

```
String sql= "update studentinfo where studentId = ? set Fname = ?,Lname = ?,gender = ?,age = ?, CNumber = ?,email = ?"
```

You are setting the `studentId` parameter at index 1 but your `?` placeholder for `studentId` is the last one in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Index for prepared statement set incorrectly.

```
    pst.setString(1,FnameTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(2, LnameTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(3, genTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(4, ageTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(5, cnmTxt.getText());
    pst.setString(6,emlTxt.getText());
    pst.setInt(7,Integer.parseInt(sidTxt.getText()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql= "update  studentinfo set Fname = ?,Lname = ?,gender = ?,age = ?, CNumber = ?,email = ? where studentId =  '"+Integer.parseInt(sidTxt.getText())+"' ";
```